# Translate a matrix with vector - but have different lines and columns?

Tags: c#

So I have a matrix 5x5 and a vector 1x3 but my simple question is...

Can I translate that matrix with this vector? because the matrix' line is unequal to the vector's column?

Comment: What does *translate* stand for in the context, please?

Comment: What are your matrix and vector supposed to be? Your question sounds a little bit like "how can I make a can opener light a fire". Is the vector representing a point in space? Or some current configuration of a network with the matrix being based on the adjacency matrix?